# Syncing map zoom level with button zooming

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

I have a MapView and a stepper button on the mapview to use for zooming in and out but the problem comes when/if the user uses pinch-to-zoom to zoom the map in and out it gets out of sync with the zoom buttons so the user could in come cases press the zoom in/zoom out and the map wont do anything.

how can i keep track of where the map zoom is so that does not happen with the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this MKMapView category : https://github.com/jdp-global/MKMapViewZoom